Question about Bochner measurability
When I study parabolic pde's I often came across the following type of Bochner spaces $L^p([a,b];L^{q}(\Omega),\ W^{1,p}([a,b];L^{q}(\Omega))$ and $L^{q}([a,b];W^{1,p}(\Omega))$ where $p,q\geq 1$ and $\Omega$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain.
I have some question about them:
1. Is there a well-writen book or article about them, covering embeddings? (the only one I know is this one which is very good https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/abschlussarbeiten/MA_Marcel_Kreuter.pdf)
2. Say that $v:[a,b]\to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $v\in L^2([a,b];W^{1,p}(\Omega))$ for some $p>1$. Is it true that $v^{+}=\max\{v,0\}:[a,b]\to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is Bochner measurable?
In fact I want to prove that $v^+,v^{-}\in L^2([a,b];W^{1,p}(\Omega))$.
It is easy to prove that $v^{+}(t,\cdot),v^{-}(t,\cdot)\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $\nabla v^{+}(t,\cdot)=\mathbf{1}_{v(t,\cdot)>0}\nabla v(t,\cdot)$ and $\nabla v^{-}(t,\cdot)=-\mathbf{1}_{v(t,\cdot)<0}\nabla v(t,\cdot)$. So, formally:
$$\int_{a}^b \Vert v^{+}(t,\cdot)\Vert^2_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}\ dt\leq \int_{a}^b \Vert v(t,\cdot)\Vert^2_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}\ dt<\infty$$
The only problem that remains is the Bochner measurability. I don't know how from a sequence of simple functions $s_n:[a,b]\to W^{1,p(x)}(\Omega)$ with:
$$s_n(t)\to v(t,\cdot)\ \text{in}\  W^{1,p}(\Omega)\ \text{for a.a.}\ t\in (a,b) $$
one can create a sequence of simple functions $\tilde{s}_n(t)\to v^{+}(t,\cdot)\ \text{in}\  W^{1,p}(\Omega)\ \text{for a.a.}\ t\in (a,b)$.
I tried to take $\tilde{s}_n(t)=s_n(t)^+$ but I have problems with the gradients...
I have obtained that $\tilde{s}_n(t)\to v^{+}(t,\cdot)$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ because $|s_n^+(t,x)-v^{+}(t,x)|\leq |s_n(t,x)-v(t,x)|$, but I don't think this is also true for gradients:
$$|\nabla s_n^+(t,x)-\nabla v^{+}(t,x)|\leq |\nabla s_n(t,x)-\nabla v(t,x)|$$
I can't beleive that if $u:[a,b]\to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is Bochner measurable it is possible that $|u|:[a,b]\to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is not Bochner measurable. But I'm stucked with the proof.
Can you please give me some advice in that situation?

You may want to check also the article by Marcel Kreuter and Wolfgang Arendt, around Example 4.9 and Section 5 in general. There are also, for example, the works by Herbert Amann, for example his Volume 1 book and this article on embeddings.

Indeed, but here the big problem is that $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is not a Banach lattice.

Fair enough, I did not read carefully enough :-) Anyway I might be very dumb here but $w \mapsto \max(w,0)$ is continuous mapping $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ into itself, so $t \mapsto \max(v(t),0)$ is measurable as the concatenation of the continuous function $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and the measurable function $t \mapsto v(t)$, mapping $[a,b] \to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, right? (E.g. right in Section 1.1 in Arendt/Batty/Hieber/Neubrander)

The all thing is how to prove that $w\mapsto\max{w,0}$ is continuous from $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ into itself.

Or the same thing: how to prove that $w\mapsto |w|$ is continuous from $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ into itself.

Every superposition operator mapping one Sobolev space into another is continuous

@Hannes Absolutely amazing! Thank you very, very much Prof. Hannes!

Sure, you are welcome. I would make this a brief answer if you don't mind. :-)

Of course! It is a very nice result that I didn't see in standard textbooks on Sobolev spaces!

Good resources for the mentioned Bochner spaces (with an emphasis on their use in abstract PDEs and the likes) could be for example

Arendt et al: Vector-valued Laplace Transforms and Cauchy Problems or the classic Hille/Phillips:  Functional Analysis and Semigroups for the construction,
the Arendt/Kreuter article that came out of the master's thesis that you mention and that tells you that $W^{1,p}(\Lambda;X)$ usually inherits embeddings from $W^{1,p}(\Lambda)$, or
Amann's Linear and Quasilinear Parabolic Problems Volume 1 for further results like density or integration by parts in time.

That being said, your particular problem can be nuked by using that

$v \colon [a,b] \to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is measurable,
if $w \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, then $w^+, w^-$ or $\lvert w\rvert$ are in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, as already observed, and
the most involved and most intriguing ingredient of Marcus/Mizel, that every superposition operator mapping one Sobolev space into another is continuous.

Then $t \mapsto v^+(t),v^-(t)$ or $\lvert v(t)\vert$ are measurable $[a,b] \to W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ as concatenations of the measurable function $v$ and the associated continuous superposition operators.
In fact, there is nothing too particular about the positive and negative part or, equivalently, the absolute value, and the argument works for any Lipschitz superposition operator.
